# Немного об этике поведения на сайте

Tags: обсуждение

**Не отвечать на комментарии – это этично?** Причем речь идет **о первом комментарии**, сделанном с целью уточнения ответа  и заданном практически сразу (или почти сразу) после ответа.  При этом отвечающий, скорее всего, **видел этот комментарий**, так как заходил на сайт уже после него. **Такая ситуация была совсем недавно и немного огорчила меня.**

Я стараюсь отвечать на комментарии всегда, **но всё-таки есть исключения.** Например, ответ был задан, на все комментарии я ответила, а через месяц или более того участник хочет уточнить дополнительные детали. Иногда отвечаю, а иногда нет.  Просто чтобы дать качественный ответ, мне нужно снова вникать в тему, а это требует времени и поэтому не очень удобно.

Answer (score 2):

Безусловно, нужно отвечать на осознанные, разумные комментарии; ведь это пойдет только на пользу ответу или вопросу!

Если кто-то игнорирует ваши комментарии, может, они просто не попались на глаза или адресат просто о них забыл. Попробуйте написать его еще раз, удалив предыдущий.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваше мнение.

Answer (score 1):

Обычная этика интернет-общения. Вежливый человек отвечает на вопрос, ему адресованный. Но не всегда, прочитав вопрос, мы можем немедленно дать ответ, а отложив дело на потом, иногда забываем о нем совсем. Так что давайте стараться отвечать, но не будем судить друг друга строго.

Comment: Есть вопросы-уточнения, на которые можно сразу дать ответ, и это очевидно. Есть вежливые люди, которые случайно не заметили комментарий (если их было просто очень много). И есть люди, для которых не отвечать на комментарии - это особый стиль поведения. Или для них отсутствие ответа - это уже и есть ответ?

Comment: @Sharon Есть таже риторические вопросы — они ответа не требуют (пример выше)  :-)

Comment: Да я без особых претензий, просто, может быть, это нормально для  интернет-общения. Неинтересен ему комментарий, вот он и не считает нужным отвечать. И все так должны делать.

Comment: @Sharon Нужно исходить из того, что интернет-общение — это то же общение, но на другой технической основе (но этическая основа не меняется). Это ненормально, если человек вежлив в обычной жизни и  хамовит  в интернете (или, скажем,  на работе, на дороге  - то же самое)

Comment: Ладно, не будем о грустном. Хорошо, что Вы всегда вежливы (или почти всегда, но это, конечно, шутка). Поздравляю Вас с Новым 2019 годом (только с прописной буквы и без запятых).

Comment: @Sharon, Спасибо, и Вас тоже поздравляю! Всегда приятно с Вами общаться.